# Response URL different from initial browser URL

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, url, python-requests

**Im getting a different URL from what was initially displayed when tried on a browser**

Facebook's docs say that a 
[Login Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U2Rw.png)
should have a format like this so using requests and urllib.parse I tried getting the response URL

```
import requests, facebook, logging

# REQUIRED AUTHENTICATION PARAMS
APP_ID = '1976346389294466'
APP_SECRET = '*************************'
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html/'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
perms = ['manage_pages','publish_pages']
fb_login_url = facebook.auth_url(app_id=APP_ID, canvas_url=REDIRECT_URI, perms=perms)
logging.debug("-----LOGIN URL:" + fb_login_url)

response = requests.get(fb_login_url, params={'response_type':'token'}, allow_redirects=True)
try:
    response.raise_for_status()
except Exception as exec:
    print("%(There was a problem)s" % (exec))

response = requests.get(response.url)
logging.debug("-----Response URL: "+response.url)
```

I'm expecting a [Expected Return URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12XpI.png) in the format of

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN...
```

However, I'm only getting the correct response when I use a browser, on my program the response returns a URL of an entirely different format

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.11%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%252F%26scope%3Dmanage_pages%252Cpublish_pages%26response_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%xxxxxxxxxxx%26ret%3Dlogin%26logger_id%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%2F%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page&locale=en_US&logger_id=xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxx
```

When I GET from the last redirect url from response.history,
the response returns a url to itself, so I'm not sure how to go about capturing
the initial value of the url such as when I use the browser

the thing is, Im not looking for anything else from the response besides the URL itself.

*Additional Notes:*

*-in the browser after getting the response url I think javascript also changes the url to blank after a brief moment for security reasons*

*-When I enter the wrong formatted url to the browser, it redirects to the right value so is there something thats handling the response differently when I'm using the browser. If so, how do grab the right url?*

**Simply put**

When I enter fb_login_url in browser I get...

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN...
```

which is what I want, but
when I do it in the app with requests...
either with `requests.get(fb_login_url).url`
OR (because of a 303) something like

```
for r in response.history:
requests.get(r.url).url
```

i get the wrong url which is

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&signed_next=1&n....
```

Comment: you should create minimal working example so everyone could run it and see problem, and try to resolve it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the top-most example runs and its most of the code as I'm only trying to do something basic. The only lines I've left out were the imports and for obvious reasons, my app_id, and app_secret which I cannot disclose. The REDIRECT_URI is 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html/' as indicated in the docs, but the main issue is when I GET from the application to fb_login_url using the app, the redirect url is different from when I enter the url in the browser manually

Comment: you could put all code - with fame `app_id`, etc. - now we don't even know what modules you use. And sometimes we are too lazy to add this manually. As for URL - it may depends on settings in facebook App Dashboard. It sends data to page with url which you have in `redirect_uri` in App Dashboard.

Comment: I worked today with Stackoverflow API which uses OAuth in similar way. In Desktop Application you can't use `fb_login_url` with `requests` but you have to use web browser to display page - and it will show login form so user can login and confirm that this application may uses his/her data. After that browser redirects to url `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` and you have to manually copy `token` to application. All those APIs were created for web applications which works all time in web browser so there is no problem with displaying login page and catching `token` from url

Comment: In Desktop App you would have to use some WebWidget to display web page with login form and catch final url `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html` with `token`.

Comment: I see, I did not know that its required to use a WebWidget to capture the token. Ill look into using pywebview and get back to you in a bit

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! that seemed to be what I was looking for. Although I'm not sure if its updated, but I also came across a method where you search browser cookies for a code and exchange that for the access token instead, this way I may not have to go through a WebWidget each time.

Comment: normally you have to get this token only once - when user uses program first time because it has to confirm that program can uses user's privated data. after that user can use the same token again and again, or sometime it has to refresh token but it doesn't need to display login form again - there should be API function to get new token using old one. So you should save token in file and read from file when you start script again.